# Is there a way to check if a bot is playing audio and if not, automatically play the next song?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, audio-streaming

I am currently in the process of creating a discord bot, using discord.py, that plays music.

The bot should play a specified song when using the '-play' command. If a song is played while the bot is currently playing, then it adds it to the queue, and once the song finishes, plays the song.

If a specified song is requested after another has finished, then it should simply play the specified song regardless.

However, currently, the bot only achieves the 1st of the two. While the song does play if queued during another song... when using the '-play' command after another song has finished, it still adds the song to the queue. The only way to play the song is to "skip" the currently playing song, even though nothing is being heard.

The related code is below:

```
class Player(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.song_queue = {}

        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            self.song_queue[guild.id] = []
    
    async def check_queue(self,ctx):
        if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) > 0:
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            await self.play_song(ctx, self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id][0])
            self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)

    async def play_song(self, ctx, song):
        url = pafy.new(song).getbestaudio().url
        ctx.voice_client.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)), after=lambda error: self.bot.loop.create_task(self.check_queue(ctx)))
        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 0.5 

#other code...

@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if song is None:
            return await ctx.send("Gotta tell me what to play before I can bust out the music")
        
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("Come on bud, why would I sing my tunes if you're not even listening!?")

        if not("youtube.com/watch?" in song or "https:youtu.be/" in song):
            await ctx.send("Searching for song, gonna have to wait a sec")
            
            result = await self.search_song(1, song, get_url=True)

            if result is None:
                return await ctx.send("Are you sure this is really a song? Maybe try search for it with my command, =play insert song name here")

            song = result[0]
            
        if ctx.voice_client.source is not None:
            queue_len = len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id])

            self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].append(song)
            return await ctx.send(f"The song's been added to your queue, position {queue_len+1}.")

        await self.play_song(ctx, song) 
        await ctx.send(f"Tonight I'll be listening to {song}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, or at least come up with a way around it. I'm still not sure as to why it adds to the queue even after a song is finished, but I fixed this with a try-except condition. Instead of using `ctx.voice.client.status`, I took advantage of an error that the program returns when attempting to play a song if another song is already playing.

Simply replace your `ctx.voice.client.status` if statement and the

```
await self.play_song(ctx, song) 
await ctx.send(f"Tonight I'll be listening to {song}")
```

with

```
try:
    await self.play_song(ctx, song)
except ClientException:
    queue_len = len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id])
    self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].append(song)
    return await ctx.send(f"I don't think you can listen to two songs at once. The 
    song's been added to your queue, position {queue_len+1}.")
```

When a song is already playing, the program raises `ClientException`, and so listening for this error lets us access the queue, and if a song isn't playing, then it'll simply play the song.